# "Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s failed: custom program error: 0x4b"

Tags: solana-program, metaplex, anchor-lang, anchor-spl

[image: My solana logs when i am trying to create metadata using metaplex]

I have also checked the error [repository](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/45a97b2edbfd6aff34df4ee3e56194008f71bba7/token-metadata/program/src/error.rs#L315) of metaplex and there i have found this msg:
"#[error("This instruction was deprecated in a previous release and is now removed")]
Removed, //For the curious we cannot get rid of an instruction in the enum or move them or it will break our api, this is a friendly way to get rid of them":

I am unsure about what actually this meant ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply means that you are calling an instruction that was deprecated and is no longer available.

You should check newer, available alternative instructions that allow you to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred for me when using Metaplex `@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata@2.10.0` to avoid singificant additional complexity with Umi in V3.

It seems the matching on chain program has been deprecated by Metaplex however [the metaplex changelog is empty](https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata/changelog).